# How to open large twitter file (30GB+) in Python?

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm wondering what's the proper script to open large Twitter files streamed using tweepy on python 3. I've used the following with smaller files but now that my data collection is above 30GB+ I'm getting memory errors:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    tweetStream = f.read().splitlines()

tweet = json.loads(tweetStream[0])
print(tweet['text'])
print(tweet['user']['screen_name'])
```

I've been unable to find what I need online so far so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your system have enough memory to store the whole file in memory at once? If not, you need to read and parse the data in parts and possibly store the intermediary to a database.

Comment: Hey Stephen, thanks for the comment. No I have only 16GB of RAM. How do people usually analyze year long twitter data that are above 1TB? Can you suggest a way to read and parse the data in parts?

Comment: See @RobBricheno 's answer below. He more or less sums up how I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and create an object that contains the entire file. Instead, as each line contains a tweet, work on the file one line at a time:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        print(tweet['text'])
        print(tweet['user']['screen_name'])
```

Perhaps store relevant tweets to another file or database, or produce a stastical summay. For example:

```
total = 0
about_badgers = 0
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        total +=1
        if "badger" in tweet['text'].lower():
            about_badgers += 1

print("Of " + str(total) +", " + str(about_badgers) +" were about badgers.")
```

Catch errors relating to unparseable lines like this:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            print(tweet['text'])
         except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            # Do something useful, like write the failing line to an error log
            pass

        print(tweet['user']['screen_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Rob, I think that should work but now I'm encountering another problem:

    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value


Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @saladin1991 perhaps the file has some blank lines? At any rate some lines cannot be decoded. I've added an example of how you might deal with that.

Comment: Rob and Stephen, thanks a lot for real. It ended up working. I really appreciate it!